# SQL server query to find duplication in a table with Yes/No displayed in rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to find the duplicated records and show it in the resultant table in a format from row to column with Y/N values in it.

Attached is my sample table and Resultant table result that I expect.
[image]

Thanks,
Kavin

Comment: Use PIVOT query, from basic search you find solution

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another SOLUTION WITHOUT PIVOT.**. A bit easy to understand as many people find pivot bit difficult to absorb.

```
SELECT * , 
         CASE WHEN [d1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN [d2] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN [d3] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN [d4] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name,SNO
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN DNO = 'd1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) [d1] 
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN DNO = 'd2' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) [d2]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN DNO = 'd3' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) [d3]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN DNO = 'd4' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) [d4]    
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Name,SNO
)y
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Name       SNO         d1   d2   d3   d4   Cnt
---------- ----------- ---- ---- ---- ---- -----------
qwe        123         Y    Y    Y    Y    4
asd        456         N    N    N    Y    1

(2 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution using PIVOT.

**Data Generation**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
     Name VARCHAR(10)
    ,SNO INT
    ,DNO VARCHAR(10)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
('qwe',123, 'd1'),
('qwe',123, 'd2'),
('qwe',123, 'd3'),
('qwe',123, 'd4'),
('asd',456, 'd4'),
('asd',456, 'd4')
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * , 'Y' N, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY name,sno) cnt FROM Table1
)
,CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT Name,SNO,
    ISNULL([d1],'N') [d1],ISNULL([d2],'N') [d2],ISNULL([d3],'N') [d3],ISNULL([d4],'N') [d4]     
    FROM CTE
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(N) FOR DNO IN ([d1],[d2],[d3],[d4])
    )t
)
SELECT * , 
         CASE WHEN [d1] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN [d2] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN [d3] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN [d4] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Cnt
FROM CTE1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Name       SNO         d1   d2   d3   d4   Cnt
---------- ----------- ---- ---- ---- ---- -----------
qwe        123         Y    Y    Y    Y    4
asd        456         N    N    N    Y    1

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Awesome. This helped. one more question, pls advice on how do I add the number of 'Y' for each row in a seperate column ?

Comment: First row has 4 Y_counts and Second row has 1 Y_counts....this information has to be captured in a new column

Comment: Hi Kavin, thanks for the update. I have updated both the solutions to include the count of Y's. Please check.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Much Pawan..You Rock!